# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference' of 'function result'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the function that i expect to get a list of `PostTag` objects from firestore.

```
class UsersDatabaseService {
  final String uid;

  UsersDatabaseService({this.uid});
  final CollectionReference settingsCollection = Firestore.instance.collection('accountSettings');
  static CollectionReference postTagListCollection= Firestore.instance.collection('postTagList');

...some code here...


static Future<List<PostTag>> getPostTags(String query)async{
    try {

      return  await postTagListCollection.where((tag) => tag.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())).getDocuments()
          .then((snapshot) => yieldPostTags(snapshot));
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }


  static List<PostTag> yieldPostTags(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    try {
      return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
        print(doc.data['name']);
        return PostTag(
          category: doc.data['category'] ?? '',
          position: doc.data['position'] ?? 0,
          name: doc.data['name'] ?? ''
        );
      }).toList();
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

I have tried this solution suggested in another similar post, that is, changing the type of `postTagListCollection` to `Query` instead of `CollectionReference` but. that came along with this error

```
I/flutter (31837): 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_query.dart': Failed assertion: line 119 pos 12: 'field is String || field is FieldPath': Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath].
```

How do i get around this error

Comment: do you get result with  print(doc.data['name']); ?

Comment: No, t does not even get to that stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `CollectionReference` is a subclass of class `Query` and since the method `collection()` returns a `CollectionReference` then you are able to do this:

```
  static CollectionReference postTagListCollection= Firestore.instance.collection('postTagList');
```

The problem is here:

```
      return  await postTagListCollection.where((tag) => tag.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase())).getDocuments()
```

The [`where()`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/query.dart#L339) method is used to query the database, for example:

```
return await postTagListCollection.where("name", isEqualTo: "john").getDocuments()
```

You can do the following queries:

```
  Query where(
    dynamic field, {
    dynamic isEqualTo,
    dynamic isLessThan,
    dynamic isLessThanOrEqualTo,
    dynamic isGreaterThan,
    dynamic isGreaterThanOrEqualTo,
    dynamic arrayContains,
    List<dynamic> arrayContainsAny,
    List<dynamic> whereIn,
    bool isNull,
  }) {
```

Comment: I see i did an err there but even after removing the .where and leaving it as  `return  await postTagListCollection.getDocuments()` i still get the error.

Comment: This error  `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'CollectionReference' of 'function result'`

Comment: Remove the static keyword and use final instead, also comment this method `yieldPostTags()`